# Unstack dataframe and keep columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unpivot

I have a DataFrame that is in a too much "compact" form. The DataFrame is currently like this :

```
> import numpy as np
> import pandas as pd

> df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['A','B'],
               'bar': ['1', '2'],
               'baz': [np.nan, '3']})
  bar  baz foo
0   1  NaN   A
1   2    3   B
```

And I need to "unstack" it to be like so :

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['A','B', 'B'],
               'type': ['bar', 'bar', 'baz'],
               'value': ['1', '2', '3']})

  foo type value
0   A  bar     1
1   B  bar     2
2   B  baz     3
```

No matter how I try to pivot, I can't get it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) method:

```
In [39]: pd.melt(df, id_vars='foo', value_vars=['bar','baz'], var_name='type')
Out[39]:
  foo type value
0   A  bar     1
1   B  bar     2
2   A  baz   NaN
3   B  baz     3
```

or

```
In [38]: pd.melt(df, id_vars='foo', value_vars=['bar','baz'], var_name='type').dropna()
Out[38]:
  foo type value
0   A  bar     1
1   B  bar     2
3   B  baz     3
```

Answer (score 3):

set your index to foo, then stack:

```
df.set_index('foo').stack()

foo     
A    bar    1
B    bar    2
     baz    3
dtype: object
```

Comment: This gives a Series and not a DataFrame

Comment: @Rémi, adding `.reset_index()` will give you desired result ;-)

Comment: Indeed, it works too. Sorry @Steven G, I can't mark both answers as correct.